# i am getting Hibernate error

Tags: java, hibernate, nio

why i am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at daoimplclasses.site_configdaoimpl.listPendingSiteConfig(site_configdaoimpl.java:41)
    at service.Config.run(Config.java:119)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'this_.temperEnabled' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1695)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3026)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1137)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1231)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: You have a wrong query. Can you post the query?

Comment: see this: ) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'this_.temperEnabled' in 'field list' at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975) at

Comment: Because there was a problem while executing the query in `at daoimplclasses.site_configdaoimpl.listPendingSiteConfig(site_configdaoimpl.java:41)` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Looking at this and your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484053/how-to-create-customized-treemap), you are misunderstanding what you can ask on Stack Overflow (and how). You may want to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) or look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Just read the stacktrace man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate generated query that can't find column `temperEnabled` in your database table.